# Upstart Script Variables That Wait For System Services To Be Available

Tags: upstart

I'm writing an upstart script that has to issue several utilities to manipulate files, ls, rm, etc.  Some of these commands are not being executed.  If I put a timer and make the script wait, they work.

**Is there a upstart variable that I can use to ensures command line utilities are fully loaded and available when my script executes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the proper way of doing things is to use events. Other Upstart scripts `emit` signals when they are doing things, this way you can have:

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
```

... and your script won't start until the filesystem and local networking are ready for business.

This still might not work for you (I'm not sure what level you need to wait until) but have a play around, listening to different events.

You can [read more about `start-on` in the cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#start-on).

Comment: Ok.  I'll give it try.  The commands I use are all in core utilities.  It would be nice to know what event makes cp or ls available.

Comment: I'd expect them to be available very early on but they're useless if you don't have a filesystem for them to work on.